# Concerning the probability of all points on a countably infinite sample space.

Tags: probability, proof-verification, infinity

Is the following Proof Correct?

> **Proposition**. Consider an experiment whose sample space consists of a countably infinite number of points. Show that not all points can be
>   equally likely.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{S} = \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\dots\}$ be the sample space for the experiment in question and assume on the contrary that $\mathbf{P}(\alpha_i) = p,\forall i\in \mathcal{S}$ where $p\in [0,1]$. 
If $p=0$ an appeal to the second and third axiom of probability implies that $1 = \mathbf{P}(\mathcal{S}) = \mathbf{P}(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{\alpha_i\}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}(\{\alpha_i\}) = 0$ resulting in a contradiction, similarly in the event 
$p\in(0,1]$ an appeal to the third axiom indicates that $\mathbf{P}(\cup_{i=1}^{\lceil\frac{1}{p}\rceil+1}\{\alpha_i\}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\lceil\frac{1}{p}\rceil+1}\mathbf{P}(\{\alpha_i\}) = (\lceil\frac{1}{p}\rceil+1)\cdot p\ge 1$ contradicting the first axiom. We may therefore conclude that our original assumption was incorrect and that the probability of all events in $\mathcal{S}$ is not equally likely.

---

$\blacksquare$

$PS:$ A Follow up question concerning the above problem also asked whethere all points have a positive probability of occurring?

I believe that the answer is no for the same reasons as those presented in the above proof for case $p\neq 0$.

Comment: Your first argument is sound.  The extension, however, is not.  Suppose $P(a_n)=2^{-n}$.

Comment: Note:  may be worth remarking that your desired result does hold if $S$ is uncountably infinite.  Exercise:  show that every uncountable sum of positive terms diverges.